# R selecting cols using columns' heads with Date types

Tags: r, csv, select

I've got csv, that has cols' heads like "2015-10-10", etc.
It's imported to R as strange X2015.10.10
I use Date class objects like 2014-12-31 and I want to get entire column, with the same date in top.
I've checked reading csv with ColClasses, etc. I need good hint.
Best,
JS

Answer (score 1):

We can use `check.names=FALSE` in the `read.csv/read.table`.  If you need to have a different column names, use `header=FALSE` which will provide default column names like `V1`, `V2`, etc.